# Code not working (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, html

I am making this program where the value in the text-box will be alerted. I know this is hardly anything, but already something isn't working. I checked the developer tools console panel and it didn't show any errors.

```html
<!DOCYTPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var submit = function() {
      var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
      alert(name);
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <form>
    <input type="text" id='name'>
    <button type="button" onclick="submit()">Submit</button>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried declaring the submit function as this: `function submit()` and not as an anonymous function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```html
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var submit1 = function() {
      var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
      alert(name);
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <form>
    <input type="text" id='name'>
    <button type="button" onclick="submit1()">Submit</button>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

That is because there's already be a function named `submit()`. Change it to `submit1()` or any other name . It'll work

Comment: This is the correct answer, although the explanation is a bit shaky.

Answer (score 3):

`submit()` is a [predefined](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_form_submit.asp) method in JavaScript that is used to submit the form.

So you can't use it like that. You need to change the function name to something else.

```
<!DOCYTPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var submitForm = function() {
      var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
      alert(name);
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <form>
    <input type="text" id='name'>
    <button type="button" onclick="submitForm()">Submit</button>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var test= function() {
      var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
      alert(name);
    }
```

```html
<input type="text" id='name'>
    <button type="button" onclick="test()">Submit</button>
```